# How to simplify exponentials into hyperbolic functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have a function of real exponentials and I'd like to simplify it using hyperbolic functions. How can I tell mathematica to use $e^x +e^{-x}=2\cosh(x)$ when simplifying? (and obviusly the $\sinh$ relation too)

Comment: `FullSimplify`?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't modify the exponentials

Comment: It works for me. You probably need to show a typical use-case in which it fails. Backup plan: `expr /. Power[E, x_] :> Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]`, which might simplify right back to exponentials if you're not careful.

Comment: `ExpToTrig` can be useful for this.

Comment: Make sure to use `E^x` not `e^x`.

Comment: You can also use `Assuming[Power[E, x_] == Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]` with `Simplify`